# How do I change the architecture of my .so file to arm64-v8a?

Tags: c++, apk, arm64

I have a file called libheloo.so (also the source code) and I want to change the architecture of it to arm64-v8a or armeabi-v7a. I looked around online but couldn't find anything. Can someone help me change the architecture to one of these please.

Answer (score 2):

[updated]
The binary is pretty useless. You'll need to rebuild the source code, probably using the exact same compiler settings as you're using for your source own code.

(Obviously, your own code also has to build for arm64-v8a if it's going to load that `.so`. After all, the whole point of an ABI is to describe how one function calls another, so the arm64-v8a ABI describes how one arm64-v8a function calls another arm64-v8a function)

Comment: I have the source code @MSalters what do I do?

Comment: @Charles Get an arm64 toolchain (assuming you don't have one already. assuming you already do or this question would be kind of pointless), point the library's build scripts at it, run the build scripts.

Comment: @user4581301 How do I do that?

Comment: @Charles that depends on the build scripts. There's a huge amount of variability. The point is you have to build the library for the platform you want the library to run on.

Comment: @user4581301 can we talk on telegram my username is: manomanny i'll pay you sir

Comment: Man, I've never sent a telegram. Maybe my great, great, great grandpa did, but I'm pretty much a phone guy, though I did send smoke signals a couple times when I was in Scouts.